# дан файл с текстом удалить из текста все пробелы

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
 
public class Main {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("text2.txt", false))
        {
            String text2 = "Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello!";          
            text2 = text2.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            writer.write(text2);
            writer.flush();
        }        
            catch(IOException ex)  {            
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
     }     
   } 
}
```

Как заменить строку `String text2 = "Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello!";`  чтобы чтение происходило из файла text

Comment: Обратите внимание, что `\s` в регулярных выражения означает не только пробелы, но и переносы строк, табуляции.  Вот эквивалент `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`

Answer (score 0):

Для чтения файла и получения из него потока строк можно использовать метод [`BufferedReader::lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) или же аналогичный метод [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (
        Stream<String> reader = Files.lines(Paths.get("text.txt"));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("text2.txt"))
    ) {
        reader
            .map(str -> str.replaceAll("\\s+", ""))
            .forEach(str -> {
                try {
                    writer.write(str);
                    writer.newLine();
                } catch (IOException ioex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to save str=" + str, ioex);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Также можно воспользоваться методом [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) для записи результатов преобразования:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> reader = Files.lines(Paths.get("text.txt"))) {
        Iterable<String> condensed = () -> reader.map(str -> str.replaceAll("\\s+", "")).iterator();
        Files.write(Paths.get("text3.txt"), condensed);
    }
}
```